How to Identify and Manage Network Drive Letter Mappings Centrally?
How can I find out which network drives (drive maps) in our company are connected to which drive letters, and is there a way to manage or query this information centrally?
Is there a cmd line or PowerShell Script?
(Im new to this so forigve me for my lack of knowledge)

Try net use.  This excludes the drives created by the subst command..  The problem with drive letters is net use and subst and USB pen drives don't know about each other.  Sometimes, if the next available letter is used by network or subst, the pen drive isn't visible to the OS.
